# Azure Service Bus: proxying topic subscription listeners

Tags: c#, azure, proxy, .net-4.5, azureservicebus

## Background

There's a RESTful API offering some operations. This RESTful API is consumed by third-parties that must be authenticated and authorized into the platform in order to get access to API's operations.

**Third-parties require reliable data consumption**, and the API must provide a *publisher/consumer* pattern-based solution to consume some data.

Since the *so-called* API won't reinvent the wheel, it's about to use ***Windows Azure Service Bus***.

## Problem

The RESTful API should abstract the actual *service bus* service. In the other hand, **Service Bus is the solution to provide reliable messaging in the own platform**.

Actually, Service Bus isn't an standalone service, but it's part of some workflows. **Third-parties aren't supposed to have Windows Azure credentials**.

Third-parties should connect to Windows Azure Service Bus using API-specific credentials that would give access to the Service Bus' topics (i.e. *message queues*).

## Possible solutions

> > ### a. *Authorize direct access to Windows Azure Service Bus*
> >
> > > It seems the easiest solution. Let's see the flow:
> > >
> > > > 1. *A third-party sends a request to the RESTful API in order to get Windows Azure Service Bus connection string - credentials -*.
> > > > 2. *Once it has the connection string, the third-party connects to Windows Service Bus and starts receving message from some topic subscription. NOTE: The connection string is encrypted in the server-side and it can only be decrypted by an accepted client.*
> > >
> > > **Pros**
> > >
> > > > - Easy. The API authorizes the third-party to use Windows Azure Service Bus and it has no other responsibility.
> > > > - Own API doesn't manage the high load of topic subscribers: this is handled by Windows Azure platform.
> > >
> > > **Cons**
> > >
> > > > - Third-parties are very tied to Windows Azure.
> > > > - Third-parties can easly by-pass the RESTful API for some time.
> >
> > ### b. *Proxy access to Windows Azure Service Bus*
> >
> > Is this ever possible? The whole flow would be:
> >
> > > > 1. *A third-party asks a TCP API similar to RESTful one in order to get subscribed to some Windows Azure Service Bus topic.*
> > > > 2. *The TCP API makes the connection and it creates a proxy in order to mirror TCP API connection to Service Bus I/O to the TCP API-to-third-party.*
> > > > 3. *Now third-party is connected to the proxy and sends and receives messages*.
> > >
> > > **Pros**
> > >
> > > > - Third-parties are connected through a proxy, meaning that they don't own any Windows Azure credential and they can't potentially by-pass the TCP or RESTful API.
> > > > - Messaging isn't absolutely tied to Windows Azure anymore.
> > >
> > > **Cons**
> > >
> > > > - What happens if Windows Azure Service Bus closes the connection?
> > > > - What happens if the platform proxy goes down?
> >
> > ### c. *Windows Azure Service Bus server wrapper*
> >
> > This is the definition and flow:
> >
> > > > 1. *The RESTful API server has pool of Windows Azure Service Bus subscription connections*.
> > > > 2. *Third-parties are subscribed to a TCP socket or WebSocket of the API server*.
> > > > 3. *Whenever Windows Azure Service Bus has a message, it's routed to the third-party connection pool and the third-party receives the message*.
> > > > 4. *Third-parties send messages using a RESTful API*.
> > >
> > > *Pros*
> > >
> > > > - Third-parties are completely agnostic of the service bus technology.
> > >
> > > *Cons*
> > >
> > > > - Same as *b.* approach.

## Questions

- Is *b.* approach possible?
- What's your advise about *c. Windows Azure Service Bus server wrapper*. Do you find an *avoidable war* the less reliability in terms of uptime and Windows Azure Service Bus to API and API to third-party synchronization?
- Am I wrong and there's some alternative to these approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I opted-in with **option a.**: **Authorize direct access to Windows Azure Service Bus.**

This is using the *Windows Azure Access Control Service*.

Using this approach, third-parties receive an Azure Service Bus connection string with an issuer (an identity) that has specific permissions on some topics. For example: "consumer can only listen".

For more details about this:

- http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/